# automatically insert in a master relationship field

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have a VF page with a master relationship field, can I insert value in this field automatically

```
<apex:inputField value="{!a.Parent__c}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is a bit vague but if you want to set a default value for the Parent__c you can just apply the value in your controller class.

EXAMPLE

```
public class VFController {
private Account controllerAccount;

//Basic Constructor
public VFController() {
    controllerAccount = new Account();
    controllerAccount.Parent__c = getDefaultParentAccount();    
}

//Standard Controller Constructor
public VFController(ApexPages.Controller standardController) {
    controllerAccount = (Account)standardController.getRecord();
    controllerAccount.Parent__c = getDefaultParentAccount();
}

private Id getDefaultParentAccount() {
    Id parentAccountId = null;

    //Lookup default parent Account
    List<Account> parentAccounts = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE /*Your Criteria here*/ LIMIT 1];
    if (parentAccounts.isEmpty() == false) {
        parentAccountId = parentAccounts[0].Id;
    }

    return parentAccountId;
}
```

}

Comment: Hello, thanks for you answer, I want to insert the master relationship field value automatically, so the user just type other fields not this one, and can I hide it ?

Comment: You can hide it from the user, sure. You might want to make it a hidden input or even an apex:variable field so that the field will still be queried by the standard controller. That way for edits you can still see that field and as long as you are setting the value in your controller class either in the save method or constructor you should be ok.